# Update RecyclerView in Fragment from MainActivity

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, android-tablayout

I have a TabLayout with a Fragment containing a RecyclerView. In the MainActivity I have a Toolbar which had the option to remove an item from the RecyclerView. I want this to happen with a remove animation (so I need to call notifyItemRemoved()) and therefore I think I cannot simply update the data-set that is passed to the RecyclerView and then reinflate the fragment. Does anyone know a way to achieve this (what code to implement in the onClick method in my MainActivity and what code in my Fragment/RecyclerViewAdapter)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your main Activity in your onClick method do something like:

```
MyFragment myFragment = (MyFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
if(myFragment != null && myFragment.isAdded(){
    myFragment.myRecyclerView.notifyItemRemoved();
}
```

Brief explanation: Like this you are retrieving the instance of your fragment inside your fragment container, a null check is always a good practice to insure you won't end up in some NPE, and then access your recycler view from your fragment instance.

Comment: oke and where do I define the id of my fragment? is it the id of the rootview of the fragment layout?

Comment: The id is the id of the fragment container, that is in the activity layout.